# How to pass variables between theme functions

Tags: theming

I often use functions that contain variables in the following files:

- Template.php
- Custom Panels Style Plugins
- node.tpl.php files
- field.tpl.php files
- views.tpl.php files

I often needed to pass variables between these functions.

At the moment, I do this by declaring my variable as a global Using PHP's global command. However, I have read that is not best practice. Is there a better way?

I know that Drupal has [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) and  [variable_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7). However, apparently these have [similar problems](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7#comment-28439) to using Globals for lots of little variables.

Comment: What is the source of your global variables. Did you retrieve these data from database on every page request?

Comment: @Xio I create them in the theme layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am newish to Drupal, but will give this a shot (I'm sure someone will tell me if I am wrong).

You can set variables that exist in different contexts by using the `template.php` file of your theme by adding stuff to the `$variables` array with preprocessor functions. So you could maybe add your variables to the `YOURTHEME_preprocess_html()` function, which should make them available everywhere.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['sample_variable'] = t('Lorem ipsum.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [hook_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7)? This hook called for all templates.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need some settings, so using variable_set is a normal practice I think.